# How to select all elements that including aimed element from data sets?

Tags: r

sheet1 is as follows, v1 presents order number.

```
v1 v2 
1 001 
2 00A
3 00B
4 100
5 A00
```

sheet2 is as follows, v1 presents order number also.

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 v5
1 001 002 
2 00C 00A 00B 
3 B00 C00 A00
4 300 100 200 500
```

excepcted sheet3 is as follows:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 v5
1 001 002 
2 00A 00C 00B 
3 00B 00C 00A
4 100 300 200 500
5 A00 B00 C00
```

I hope column v1 and column v2 based in sheet1 are not changed, then search all elements in sheet2 that is in same row with v2 in sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think merge can do the trick here, but this should bring you close at least:

```
sheet3 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(sheet1)){
    for (k in 1:nrow(sheet2)){
        if (sheet1[i, "v2"] %in% sheet2[k,]) {
            sheet3 <- rbind(sheet3, cbind(sheet1[i, "v1"], sheet2[k,-1]))
        }
    }
}
```

it still needs some tweaking, plus I am pretty sure there is a more R like way to do this.